# Trying crawling, but the only one works, not the others

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

token=''
chat_id = 
bot = telegram.Bot(token)
updater = Updater(token=token)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
updater.start_polling()

bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text='Welcome!')


def handler(update, context):
    text = update.message.text
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id

    if 'bot' in text:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Did you call me?')

    if text.startswith("hi"):
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='Hello')

    if text.startswith("eth"):
        html = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        price = soup.find('td').text
        change = soup.find('p',{'class': 'sc-1eb5slv-0 sc-1siv958-1 lfjNAJ'}).text
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='CURRENT ETH PRICE' + '\n' + price + '\n' + 'IN USD' + '\n' + 'LAST 24 HOURS' + '\n' + change)

    if text.startswith("DFM"):
        html = requests.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0x0ccD5DD52Dee42B171a623478e5261C1eaaE092A")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        priced = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-6'}).find_all('span', {'class':'d-block'}).text
        pricede = soup.find('span', {'class': 'small text-secondary text-nowrap'}).text
        circu = soup.find('button', {'class': 'u-label u-label--sm u-label--value u-label--text-dark u-label--secondary rounded'}).text
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='CURRENT DFM token PRICE' + '\n' + priced + '\n' + 'IN USD' + '\n' + pricede + '\n' + 'IN ETH' + '\n' + 'CIRCULATING SUPPLY MARKET CAP' + circu)
            
echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)
```

The first crawling with eth does work, but the other one, DFM, does not work. I couldn't find out what the problem is. And I tried to crawl eth from
https://ethereum.org/en/get-eth/ but I couldn't as well.

```
##price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-6'}).text
##price = soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"col-6"}).find_all("span", attrs={"class":"d-block"}).text
##price = soup.select_one('div.col-6 span.d-block').text
```

These are other codes I tried in the other way. I do not know what information is needed to understand my situation, I use Python Idle.

Comment: page  https://ethereum.org/en/get-eth/ uses JavaScript to add elements but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript` so they can't get elements added by JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: open browser, turn off JavaScript and then load your urls - and you will see what you can get with `requests`/`BeautifulSoup`

Comment: page https://etherscan.io/token/0x0ccD5DD52Dee42B171a623478e5261C1eaaE092A also uses JavaScript to display elements - so `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can be useless. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or you may have to search used by JavaScript to get data from server - and then you may try to use this url with `requests`

Comment: it seems page `etherscan.io` display price even without JavaScript but when I run your code then I get error because it can't find it. I didn't check yet what server sends to code - maybe it sends warning for bots/scripts/spamers/hackers - or it needs headers in `requests` to recognize device/system/browser and send correct HTML. Some portals send different HTML for different devices - phone, tablet, desktop.

Answer (score 1):

For `DFM` I needed two changes.

First: it needs `find()` instead of `find_all()` in line

```
priced = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-6'}).find('span', {'class':'d-block'}).text
```

Second: it needs header `User-Agent` in `requests`.

It can be even incomplete `User-Agent` like `'Mozilla/5.0'`

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'}

url = "https://etherscan.io/token/0x0ccD5DD52Dee42B171a623478e5261C1eaaE092A"

html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

---

```
if text.startswith("DFM"):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}# (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'}
    url = "https://etherscan.io/token/0x0ccD5DD52Dee42B171a623478e5261C1eaaE092A"
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    priced = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-6'}).find('span', {'class':'d-block'}).text
    pricede = soup.find('span', {'class': 'small text-secondary text-nowrap'}).text
    circu = soup.find('button', {'class': 'u-label u-label--sm u-label--value u-label--text-dark u-label--secondary rounded'}).text
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text='CURRENT DFM token PRICE' + '\n' + priced + '\n' + 'IN USD' + '\n' + pricede + '\n' + 'IN ETH' + '\n' + 'CIRCULATING SUPPLY MARKET CAP' + circu)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dfm_token = "0x0ccD5DD52Dee42B171a623478e5261C1eaaE092A"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}# (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'}
url = f"https://etherscan.io/token/{dfm_token}"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 'html5lib')

price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-6'}).find('span', {'class': 'd-block'}).text.strip()
price_USD, price_ETH = price.split('@')

price_USD = price_USD.strip()[1:]   # skip `$` at the beginning
price_ETH = price_ETH.strip()[:-4]  # skip `Eth` at the end

cap = soup.find('button', {'class': 'u-label u-label--sm u-label--value u-label--text-dark u-label--secondary rounded'}).text.strip()

print(f'TOKEN: {dfm_token}\nUSD: {price_USD}\nETH: {price_ETH}\nCAP: {cap}')
```

Result:

```
TOKEN: 0x0ccD5DD52Dee42B171a623478e5261C1eaaE092A
USD: 0.0716
ETH: 0.000045
CAP: $143,150,000.00
```

---

**EDIT:**

Page https://ethereum.org/en/get-eth/ uses `JavaScript` to add values to HTML but `requests`, `BeautifulSoup` don't run `JavaScript`.

But using `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) I found url used by `JavaScript` to read these values as JSON - and I can use it with `requests` to get them - event without `BeautifulSoup`

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=ethereum&vs_currencies=usd&include_24hr_change=true'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json() 

price = data['ethereum']['usd']
change = data['ethereum']['usd_24h_change']

print(f'price: {price}')
print(f'change: {change:.2f}%')
```

Results

```
price: 1578.36
change: -2.48%
```

---

It seems there is free API on https://www.coingecko.com/en/api which you can use to get prices without scraping - using only `requests` without `BeautifulSoup`